# iOS11 How to create contact detail in NavigationBar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'd like to create a navigation bar with this iOS11 detail as in the Contacts app.

How to create a navigation bar like this with resizable image and action buttons?

[image: Contact detail in Navigation bar]

Comment: Do you just want a navigation bar with more height? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Yes, more height, resizing image and actions message, call, video, home.... I'm looking for a component that uses in apple for phone contact detial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no component in `UIKit`. However there is a sample project how to implement this with a custom view:

https://github.com/lukaswuerzburger/resizeable-tableview-header

[image]